# Distinction between one UITableView displaying different array in segmented control. How to implement swipe for delete only in one segment

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have one UITableView, two arrays and segmented control. When segmented control index is "1", UITableView display data from first array, when index is "2" - second array. I want to swipe to delete function only in second segment. How can I do that? I am thinking of some "if statements" in

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle:
UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

but i don't know where to put them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `commitEditingstyle`, then your cells will still display the Delete button when you swipe.  Use `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` instead.  Put an if statement in to test which segment is selected, and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None` (to disable swipe to delete) or `.Delete` (to enable swipe to delete) accordingly.  If you want to be able to delete the cells by putting the table view into editing mode, then also test `tableView.editing` to determine whether to use `.Delete` or `.None`.

Comment: Thank You, great answer, but it works only if commitEditingstyle function is add as well. Only then I can swipe my finger and see delete. Why? It is working, but I don't understand how.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you need to implement commitEditingStyle as well.  The `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` is called by the table view when you swipe your finger, to determine whether it should display the Delete button or not.  `commitEditingStyle` is only called when you press the delete button, so that you can implement the necessary code to remove the row.